# Stacking multiple TikZ tree labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-trees, linguistics, syntax

I have a question related to the labelling of TikZ circles within a forest tree. Is it possible to stack multiple labels below the circle so that they would appear under one another, like this?

something 1
something 2
something 3

This is the code I'm working with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{default preamble={for tree={s sep=7mm, inner sep=-1, l=0}}, fairly nice empty nodes/.style={delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for siblings={anchor=north}}{}},for tree={s sep=4mm}},}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
           [[\textsc{AP},tikz={\node [draw,circle,inner sep=-1pt,fit to=tree,label=below:\emph{something 1}] {};}[\textsc{CP}[...,roof]] [\textsc{DP}[...,roof]]][\textsc{EP}[...,roof]]]
        \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I already tried:

- double dashes: `label=below: \emph{something 1 \\ something 2}`
- putting this after the forest: `\emph{something 1} \ \ \hspace{1cm} \emph{something 2}`, but then the text isn't neatly aligned
- adding more than one label: `label=below: \emph{something 1}, label=below: \emph{something 2}`, but then they are just added next to each other

For now, I've temporarily solved it by just positioning a text box in the right place, but I find it takes a lot of fidgeting with the coordinates, so a quicker solution would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Oh thanks for the comment - would it pass as a minimal working example now?

Comment: Yes, it does pass.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment. Even though I've used Tex StackExchange for the longest time, I'm somehow still figuring out how things work.

Comment: Why are you loading so many packages for trees? Certainly your example here doesn't need them, but do you even need them in your real document?

Comment: Note that you don't need to fiddle with coordinates. Aside from being able to name nodes for reference, you can use e.g. `tikz+` and relative node names to add arbitrary tikz stuff using forest's own referencing system.

Comment: @cfr Re packages: I am no expert in Tex, so I must admit I simply copy-pasted bits and pieces from some source codes that others provided me with... I will try to understand the content of the packages better at some point, but for now, I'm just happy trees appear on the paper as I want them... Re coordinates: thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ally69710 It's often easier to just comment out lines you're not sure about and see if the thing still compiles ;). Loading stuff you don't need is a common source of problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Adaptation

- (I added some line breaks for better readability)
- give the first node a name `(a)`
- place a second node below (using `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`), with option `align=center`, to allow line breaks

OR for the same result with the `label` option in one node:

```
\node [
    draw,circle,inner sep=-1pt,fit to=tree,
    label={[align=center]below:{\emph{something 1}\\something 2\\something 3}}
] (a) {};
```

#### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    default preamble={for tree={s sep=7mm, inner sep=-1, l=0}},
    fairly nice empty nodes/.style={delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for siblings={anchor=north}}{}},for tree={s sep=4mm}},
}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
   [
       [
            \textsc{AP},
            tikz={
                \node [draw,circle,inner sep=-1pt,fit to=tree] (a) {};
                \node [below=0mm of a, align=center] {\emph{something 1}\\something 2\\something 3};
            }
            [\textsc{CP}[...,roof]]
            [\textsc{DP}[...,roof]]
       ][
        \textsc{EP}[...,roof]
       ]
   ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]